# Copying sd card with dd, can't boot: "sh: can't access tty; job control turned off"

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, linux, image

I have a working SD card which I want to back up to an `.img` file and be able to quickly replicate.

I'm using `dd` to copy my image to my sd card:

```
dd if=raspbian.img of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
```

Which executes successfully. When I inspect the contents of the sd card afterwards everything seems ok, boot partition contains all necessary files etc..

When I try to boot I get the rainbow screen after which it starts the boot process, I assume, and it gets stuck at

```
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

Nothing seems to be wrong with the original card, it works every time, so I spent about 5 hours trying to figure out what the issue was, reading through countless posts on here containing the same error which were all unrelated. I finally figured it out, I'm posting this in case I can save someone else's time in future.

Comment: Why the f did whoever downvote this question?

Answer (score 1):

It spent a lot of time looking at the image contents and all kinds of errors related to the header pins being shorted, modifying `cmdline.txt` and `config.txt` and more...

In the end the error turned out to be the way I was generating the image. Since my SD card is 32GB and I definitely don't want a 32GB image, I did some calculation to extract just about what my filesystem size was, off of the original card, using the `count` parameter on the `dd` command. My calculation was a bit off and my image ended up being ~100MB smaller than the content of the SD card. I don't know how that lead to the error I was experiencing as I believe that would have been ~100MB short off the `rootfs` partition, but apparently it affected it in some way. After generating a proper `img` file, slightly bigger than my contents' size, everything works as expected.